# convergence of max almost surely

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_{n}$ be the sequence of real IID random variable with distribution funtion F. Show that
\begin{equation*}
\max(X_1, X_2, ...X_n) \rightarrow \sup\{x \in \mathbb{R}|F(x)<1\}
\end{equation*}
almost surely.
I am thinking to apply same idea as for any epsilon we show sum $P(|M_{n}-c|> \epsilon) < \infty$ where $M_{n}$ is maximum of $(X_1,..., X_{n})$ and $c$ the supremum. Yet couldn't complete properly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all using real analysis, the sequence of random variables $M_n$ is nondecreasing and bounded above by $c$ hence it must converge almost surely to some random variable $M$ satisfying $M\leq c$. It remains to show that $M=c$ a.s. For this, observe that since $M_n \leq M$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(M\leq c-\epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(M_n\leq c-\epsilon)= \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq c-\epsilon)^n = F(c -\epsilon)^n.$$
By definition of $c$, $F(c-\epsilon) < 1$. In particular, $F(c-\epsilon)^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(M\leq c-\epsilon) = 0$ for every $\epsilon>0$. This proves that $M=c$ a.s.

Comment: Suppose $F$ is standard normal. What is your $c$? I presume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: In that case $c = +\infty$. You're right to point it out as in my proof it was implicit that $c<+\infty$. But you can adapt it to that case, just replace $c-\epsilon$ with an arbitrary constant $A$ to show that $M\geq A$ a.s. for any $A$. @Galton